# Extending Activity with onKeyUp/onKeyDown in NativeScript, but the Events are not triggered

Tags: android, nativescript

I followed the NativeScript tutorial to extend Activity at this page:

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

The extended activity worked, so I went on and added my own onKeyUp and onKeyDown codes:

```
onKeyDown: function (keyCode, event) {
    console.log(keyCode);
    return this._callbacks.onKeyDown(this, keyCode, event, superProto.onKeyDown);
},
onKeyUp: function (keyCode, event) {
    console.log(keyCode);
    return this._callbacks.onKeyUp(this, keyCode, event, superProto.onKeyUp);
},
```

I made sure that my modified Activity was in use by adding a console.log inside onCreate to print out a message. And the Activity still worked (as I could see that message in the log), but the onKeyUp and onKeyDown were never fired. At the same time, the onBackPressed event that's in the sample Activity in the tutorial was correctly fired when I pressed the back button (I added a console.log to check).

FYI, I understand that software keyboard may not trigger the two key events, but I was using a Bluetooth keyboard. I also verified that the Bluetooth keyboard was indeed connected and working.

Comment: Did you try a clean build? Did you modify the default Android callbacks implemented in the framework, otherwise you wouldn't have to call `this._callbacks.onKeyUp` or `this._callbacks.onKeyDown` those which will be undefined.

Comment: You SAVED MY DAY, again. Did a clean build and the key events were fired. And it immediately threw an error because, as you said, `this._callbacks.onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` are both undefined. 

I changed it to return false and that got rid of the error. But that seems to block `onBackPressed`. So, I changed it to return `this._callbacks.onSaveInstanceState(this, event, superProto.dispatchKeyEvent);` However, that triggered a **RangeError: maxmium call stack size exceeded**.

Comment: `this._callbacks.onSaveInstanceState(this, event, superProto.dispatchKeyEvent);` should be `this._callbacks.dispatchKeyEvent(this, event, superProto.dispatchKeyEvent);` but after some digging, I found that *AndroidActivityCallbacks* does not define `dispatchKeyEvent` either. 

Anyway, I determined that I shouldn't call back to *dispatchKeyEvent* at all because it will create an infinite cycle (which was why I got the max call stack size exceeded error). I've tried both returning *false* and *true* (obviously the wrong choice, I had to tried it to make sure).

Comment: I also tried skipping `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` entirely and override `dispatchKeyEvent`, but since *this._callbacks* does not have a `dispatchKeyEvent`, I don't know how to call the superclass's `dispatchKeyEvent`. I've tried calling `superProto.dispatchKeyEvent`, but I got the following error:

`The JavaScript instance no longer has available Java instance counterpart.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Manoj's help, I found an answer. First of all, my original problem is not code related. After I did a clean build, as suggested by Manoj, the two key events were fired without any problem.

But that brought up a different problem. As mentioned by Manoj (again), I could not simply call the superclass's **onKeyUp** and **onKeyDown** because the **this._callbacks** does not contain the two members.

I decided not to catch the key event in **onKeyUp** and **onKeyDown** at all. Instead, I chose to override the **dispatchKeyEvent**. Again, I faced the same problem, how could I call the super *dispatchKeyEvent*? It turned out that I could not simply do:

```
    dispatchKeyEvent: function (event) {
        console.log("Dispatch Key Event");
        return superProto.dispatchKeyEvent (event);
    }
```

If I did that, I would get an error saying: ***The JavaScript instance no longer has available Java instance counterpart.***

Instead, I need to call the super **dispatchKeyEvent** the following way:

```
    dispatchKeyEvent: function (event) {
        console.log("Dispatch Key Event");
        return superProto.dispatchKeyEvent.call(this, event);
    }
```

This worked like a charm!

Comment: toyosamurai, how did you catch this events in app later?
could you answer this or in separate question here, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381277/how-catch-android-dispatchkeyevent-in-nativescript-app