# How catch android dispatchKeyEvent in nativescript app?

Tags: android, nativescript

Extended dispatchKeyEvent in Activity for listening volume up/down key press events in android.

(as described here: [How to listen for volume up/down key in android with nativescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943511/how-to-listen-for-volume-up-down-key-in-android-with-nativescript/45943736))

But can't figure out how to catch this events in app.

This process described here with all events but dispatchKeyEvent:  https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#android-activity-events

```
application.android.on( <what should be here?>, function (args) {
    console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity);
});
```

Comment: Do you wants to capture the life cycle events ?

Comment: I want capture volume up/down keys - don't know  are they life cycle or not =)

Comment: as understood - they are "life cycle events" indeed

Comment: I'm not sure maybe the following link helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943511/how-to-listen-for-volume-up-down-key-in-android-with-nativescript

Comment: sorry, but i pointed to this link in question - it was answer that helped me to get the event, but issue is that i don't know how to access this event inside application.

Answer (score 0):

activity.android.js

```
case android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
application.notify({
    eventName:'KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP',
})
// console.log("KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP");
return true;
```

inside application

```
    const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");
    if (application.android) {
      application.on('KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP', this.onVolumeUp);
      application.on('KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN', this.onVolumeDown);
    }
```